# Bordered table rows and spacing with CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table wherein I need to put a border around a given row or rows with spacing between them.

I seem to be able to do one or the other.

I know I can use

```
table { border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 1em 0.5em; }
```

To get my spacing, but then the border won't show up with something like

```
tr.bordered { border: 1px solid blue; }
```

If I set `border-collapse: collapse`, the blue border shows.  But then no spacing.

Am I missing something here?

EDIT: [JS FIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/smlombardi/2nMcg/1/)

You can see, if you use "collapse", the border works but there is no space.

If you use "separate" you get spacing but no border.

Comment: Might be helpful to have a jsfiddle for somthing like this.

Comment: Or add a drawing of the result you want. It is unclear to me were you want the borde and spacing to appear.

Comment: added a fiddle.  I need spacing between rows and columns, but I also need the specified row to have a border.

Comment: Have you tried using padding on table cells instead? Like `td { padding: .5em; }`

Comment: This is what you wanted:http://jsfiddle.net/6rLsL/1/show (see my answer below)

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate question here: [Style row or column rather than cells when border-collapse: separate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035413/style-row-or-column-rather-than-cells-when-border-collapse-separate)

The recommendation is to use colspan to simulate a table row, and add a border to the table inside of the colspan.

Comment: The colspan seems total overkill. You can do this with no extra colspans or other. http://jsfiddle.net/6rLsL/1/

Comment: that works with background-color, which I might end up using, but not border. See http://jsfiddle.net/6rLsL/2/

Comment: @seanna Yes I thought of a nested table, but i will have many rows and then it gets tricky to get all the columns to align.  The idea of using a table in the first place is so I can align tabular data.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is to put spaces between the borders of the cell and its data? If so, you can use the property padding in td. ex:

```
td {
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to draw an unblured shadow : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2nMcg/3/)**

```
.bordered {
    box-shadow:0 0 0 1px black;
}
```

:( this works in FF , but ...

---

so , 
we can use `:first-child` and `:last-child` to draw borders from `td`s,

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/2nMcg/8/)**

---

```
.bordered td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-left:none;
    border:right:none;
    padding:1em 0.5em;
    border-right:none;
}
.bordered td:first-child {
    border-left:1px solid #000
}
.bordered td:last-child {
    border-right:1px solid #000;
    border-left:none;
} 
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have an inner table which is bordered:

```
<table>
    <tr><td colspan="3">

    <table  class="bordered">
        <tr>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>bar</td>
            <td>baz</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    </td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>lorem</td>
        <td>ipsum</td>
        <td>dolor</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2nMcg/7/**

Answer (score 0):

If you want spacing between the table rows and add a border style to each row you can achieve this by setting only top and bottom border-spacing otherwise you cannot have a continuous line for each table row. And you need to set the border style on the td. Since border-collapse: collapse prevents to style the border on the TR element but you need it to set the top and bottom spacing between rows.
http://jsfiddle.net/6rLsL/1/
http://jsfiddle.net/6rLsL/1/show

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0 0.5em;
}

td {
   padding: 0.5em;
   border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
```